# How can I reach my table in MS Azure after I connected my database in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

After I connected to the MS Azure Database to Anylogic, I couldn't see the table I only used and built. 4 table shown which I have never seen before : dbo_sysdac_history_internal, dbo_sysdac_instances_internal, sys_trace_xe_action_map, sys_trace_xe_event_map . How can I reach my table directly and why my table was not shown?

Even it's not right away, I want to reach my table like selecting SELECT * FROM my_table; . Actually I wonder why I cannot see the table right away.I would be very glad if you could help me. Thanks.
#Anylogic

Comment: How have you connected and what are the dbase properties?

Comment: At first I had an issue with connecting MS Azure because of TLS versions. However, I solved this problem by adding "ssl=require" to the end of my Host gap in Anylogic. What do you mean by properties? It's SQL database. It would be great if you can specify the thing you need to now. The table can be called from other software like Azure data Studio and SQL Server Management Studio.